# Getting the list of all branches in a GitHub organisation without triggering Rate Limit, using Bash?

Tags: github, rss, branch, rate-limiting, atom-feed

While trying to establish a list of incoming GitHub commits I've stumbled accross the GitHub rate api limits, of 60 calls per hour. As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12398912/7437143), one can get the lists of branches with an API call using:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{username}/{repo-name}/branches
```

However, that triggers the rate limit for the average GitHub organisation/user. So I thought I'd try a different approach, using RSS/atom format. However, as that same answer explains, the  atom format/rss feed seems to depend on the user having a list of all branches in a repository. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353538/setting-up-a-github-commit-rss-feed) asks for an overview of all commits in a repository, yet instead it is given an answer for all commits in the default branch of the repository. And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388091/fetch-commits-from-multiple-branches-of-repo-hosted-on-github) receives a working answer that triggers the rate limit, as it relies on at least 1 API call per repository.

Hence, I would like to ask: *How could one get a list of all branches of a GitHub user, using at most 1 GitHub API call?*

Note, using atom views would be perfectly fine, however, I have not found an atom view like: `https://github.com/:owner/:repo/commits.atom` or `https://github.com/:owner/:repo/branches.atom` that displays all branches in a repository. I would strongly prefer a solution that does not rely on a third party like: https://rsshub.app/github/repos/yanglr as I imagine, they too will at some point start rate-limiting.

My current approach is to scrape the source code of `https://github.com/:user/:repo/branches` using bash. However, I imagine there might exist a more efficient solution to this.

### MWE

Thanks to the comments, I was ble to find a bash MWE to perform a GraphQL query using terminal. It is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51895358/7437143), where `bearer` is not a variable, it is the means of identification and the `......` should be your personal GitHub Access token. I am currently looking into how to get the repositories beyond the 1st hundred. Then I'll look at how to get the branches of those repositories.

### Attempt I

The following query yields a `json` with the repositories and first 4 branches in each repository of a user!

name:`examplequery.gql`.

```
query {
  repositoryOwner(login: "somegithubuser") {
    repositories(first: 40) {
      edges {
        node {
          nameWithOwner
          refs(
            refPrefix: "refs/heads/"
            orderBy: { direction: DESC, field: TAG_COMMIT_DATE }
            first: 4
          ) {
            edges {
              node {
                ... on Ref {
                  name
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Next, a bash script is made that runs the query:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Runs graphql query on GitHub. Execute with:
# ./run_graphql_query.sh examplequery1.gql

GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN_GLOBAL="your_github_personal_access_token"

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "usage of this script is incorrect."
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -f $1 ];then
    echo "usage of this script is incorrect."
    exit 1
fi

# Form query JSON
QUERY=$(jq -n \
           --arg q "$(cat $1 | tr -d '\n')" \
           '{ query: $q }')


curl -s -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: bearer $GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN_GLOBAL" \
  --data "$QUERY" \
  https://api.github.com/graphql
```

It can be ran with:

```
./run_graphql_query.sh examplequery1.gql
```

There are two more issues to resolve before I can answer the question. How I can iterate over all repositories instead of only the first 100. How I can parse the json into a list of branches per repository.

Comment: Did you try using the GraphQL API?

Comment: My guess would be to use the graph API so get all of that in a single go. But I'm not versed well enough in the query language to tell you how to do it. https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer and https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/about-the-graphql-api

Comment: @jonrsharpe and @jessehouwing, thank you for the suggestion, I have not yet looked at that. It seems to be what I am looking for, since the amount of data I want is small yet specific, compared to what is typically returned in a single API call like: `https://github.com/:owner/:repo/commits.atom`. I will look into it!